# How can i use this script with 2 buttons

Tags: javascript

I've got this script which is working fine but i have 2 download buttons, one called downloadButton and one called downloadButtonUS.

How can i make it so when either button is clicked?

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('.downloadButton').click(function(){
    $(".dlm").replaceWith(function(){
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do: `$('.downloadButton,.downloadButtonUS')`